# FIR Filter Design - obtaining FIR coefficients from frequency response

Tags: fft, filters, audio

I would like to obtain FIR filter (low-pass) coefficients from a given frequency response by using C++ to develop algorithms. I have read at http://iowahills.com/B2PolynomialFIRFilters.html, that, if done properly, almost any filter response can be implemented as an FIR. In principle, one simply does an Inverse Fourier Transform on the filter's frequency response. Is there a C or C++ code that will do this? Any links or detailed guidelines how to solve this would be appreciated! I want to thank member [hotpow2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/154/hotpaw2) for suggesting gradient descent routine, but I need more details on that as well.

Comment: The method you're referring to is called *frequency sampling method*, and [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/fir-filter-design-with-frequency-sampling-method-setting-proper-phase-response) and its answers may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's some very old source in C to do an FFT.  it's nowhere near as good as FFTW, but it's free and self-contained.

if you're doing this inverse DFT and windowing (i would recommend the Kaiser window) to design an FIR, probably it doesn't need to be an FFT.  you can write a very simple DFT (no Cooley-Tukey radix-2 optimizations) and run it.  i don't think you'll care too much if it takes a couple of seconds longer to run.

```
/*  
A set of utility programs to compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT):

                       N-1
                X[k] = SUM { x[n]exp(-j2(pi)nk/N) }
                       n=0

and inverse Fast Fourier Transform (iFFT):

                           N-1
                x[n] = 1/N SUM { X[k]exp(+j2(pi)nk/N) }
                           k=0

To speed things up, multiplication by 1 and j are avoided.  The input, x[],
is an array of complex numbers (pairs of doubles) of length N = 2^p.  The
calling program supplies p = log2(N) not the array length, N.  The output
is placed in BIT REVERSED order in x[].  Call bitreverse(x, p) to swap back
to normal order, if needed.  However, iFFT(X, p, trigtbl) requires its input,
X[], to be in bit reversed order making bit reversing unnecessary in some
cases, such as fast convolution.  trigtbl is an array of doubles of length
N/4 containing the sin function from 0 to pi/2 used to compute the FFT.
Call sintable(trigtbl, p) ONLY ONCE before either FFT(x, p, trigtbl) or
iFFT(X, p, trigtbl) to set up a sin table for FFT computation.

Written in Megamax C (for the Mac) by Robert Bristow-Johnson (1985).
*/

/*
#include <complex.h>
*/

typedef struct {
double real;
double imag;
} complex;

#define Re(z) (z).real
#define Im(z) (z).imag

#define PI (3.14159265359)

double sin();

FFT (x, p, trigtbl)
complex x[];
int p;
register double *trigtbl;
{
register long length, step, stepsize, size;
register complex *top, *bottom, *end;               /* top & bottom of FFT butterfly */
complex temp;

size = 1L<<p;
end = x + size;

length = size>>1;   
size >>= 2;
stepsize = 1L;
while ( length > 1L) {
    top = x;
    while (top < end) {
        bottom = top + length;

        Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);          /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
        Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
        Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
        Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
        *bottom = temp;
        top++;
        bottom++;

        for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
            Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);      /* butterfly: twiddle = exp(-jÌ) */
            Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
            Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
            Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
            Re(*bottom) = Re(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] + Im(temp)*trigtbl[step];
            Im(*bottom) = Im(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(temp)*trigtbl[step];
            top++;
            bottom++;
        }

        Re(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);          /* butterfly: twiddle = -j */
        Im(temp) = Re(*bottom) - Re(*top);
        Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
        Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
        *bottom = temp;
        top++;
        bottom++;

        for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
            Re(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);      /* butterfly: twiddle = -j*exp(-jÌ) */
            Im(temp) = Re(*bottom) - Re(*top);
            Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
            Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
            Re(*bottom) = Re(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] + Im(temp)*trigtbl[step];
            Im(*bottom) = Im(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(temp)*trigtbl[step];
            top++;
            bottom++;
        }
        top = bottom;
    }
    stepsize <<= 1;
    length >>= 1;
}

top = x;
bottom = x + 1;
while (top <  end) {
    Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);              /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
    Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
    Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
    Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
    *bottom = temp;
    top += 2;
    bottom += 2;
}
}


iFFT (X, p, trigtbl)
complex X[];
int p;
register double *trigtbl;
{
register long length, step, stepsize, size;
double scale;
register complex *top, *bottom, *end;               /* top & bottom of FFT butterfly */
complex temp;

size = 1L<<p;
end = X + size;

scale = 1.0/(double)size;
top = X;
bottom = X + 1;
while (top <  end) {
    Re(temp) = (Re(*top) - Re(*bottom))*scale;      /* butterfly: twiddle = 1/N */
    Im(temp) = (Im(*top) - Im(*bottom))*scale;
    Re(*top) = (Re(*top) + Re(*bottom))*scale;
    Im(*top) = (Im(*top) + Im(*bottom))*scale;
    *bottom = temp;
    top += 2;
    bottom += 2;
}

length = 1L;
size >>= 2;
stepsize = size;
while ( stepsize >= 1L) {
    length <<= 1;
    top = X;
    while (top < end) {
        bottom = top + length;

        temp = *bottom;                             /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
        Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
        Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
        Re(*top) += Re(temp);
        Im(*top) += Im(temp);
        top++;
        bottom++;

        for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                                                    /* butterfly: twiddle = exp(+jÌ) */
            Re(temp) = Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
            Im(temp) = Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] + Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
            Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
            Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
            Re(*top) += Re(temp);
            Im(*top) += Im(temp);
            top++;
            bottom++;
        }

        Re(temp) = -Im(*bottom);                    /* butterfly: twiddle = +j */
        Im(temp) = Re(*bottom);
        Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
        Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
        Re(*top) += Re(temp);
        Im(*top) += Im(temp);
        top++;
        bottom++;

        for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                                                    /* butterfly: twiddle = +j*exp(+jÌ) */
            Re(temp) = -Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
            Im(temp) = Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
            Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
            Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
            Re(*top) += Re(temp);
            Im(*top) += Im(temp);
            top++;
            bottom++;
        }
        top = bottom;
    }
    stepsize >>= 1;
}
}


sintable(trigtbl, p)
register double *trigtbl;
int p;
{
register long size, i;
double theta;

size = 1L<<(p-2);
theta = (PI/2.0)/(double)size;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    trigtbl[i] = sin(theta*(double)i);
}


bitreverse (x, p)
register complex *x;
int p;
{
complex temp;
register long k, i, r, size, count;

size = (1L<<p) - 1L;
for (k = 1L; k < size; k++) {
    i = k;
    r = 0;
    for (count = size; count > 0; count >>= 1) {
        r <<= 1;
        r += (i & 0x00000001L);
        i >>= 1;
    }
    if (r > k) {
        temp = x[r];
        x[r] = x[k];
        x[k] = temp;
    }
}
}
```