# Numerical Calculation of impulse response out of frequency response

Tags: finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, impulse-response

Currently I work on my Masterthesis which deals with structural dynamic simulation. As a part of it I have to filter a Signal with a FIR-Filter. From that Filter I know the Frequency Response (picture).[image: Frequency Response]

The code is written in Python and I'm not sure how to apply the IFFT since I have just a real input.

---

Thank you for your answer robert bristow-johnson!

In python there is function called irfft which stands for inverse real fft. So a ifft for real input. But it seems that something goes wrong with the time signal. I'm aware of that I have no phase in this case. But I guess for Filters in Signal processing it is pretty common to just have the frequency response and calculate the impulse response out of it? So there should be a right way to do it...
Unfortunately I'm no expert in Signal processing and at the moment I'm pretty much stuck at this problem.

UPDATE: I think the correct way is to add just zero phase (so +0j) to the frequency response. For the ifft the first bin has to be 0 valued, from 1 - N/2 i add my frequencies as I have it from the response, and from N/2 - N I add the conjugate complex numbers (as the phase is zero the values are just in  descending order). 
Hope this will do the trick.

Comment: you don't have enough information to calculate an impulse response if you don't have the phase of the frequency response.  there are some things you can do to **infer** the phase response, but the best is to measure it when the amplitude response is measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the [frequency sampling design method](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Frequency_Sampling_Method_FIR.html), which results in a linear phase FIR filter. You sample the desired magnitude on an equidistant grid, add a linear phase term, and then you compute the impulse response by taking an inverse DFT. The resulting impulse response is usually windowed. I've explained the details in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/19630/4298), which also includes some Matlab/Octave code. Note that windowing is not done in that simple code fragment.

Comment: @Michael: You're welcome :)